# Selecting n-th to last values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like so:

```
id device  group    
-----------------
1  a       1000
2  a       1000        
3  b       1001
4  b       1001
5  b       1001
6  b       1002
8  a       1003
9  a       1003
10 a       1003
11 a       1003
12 b       1004
13 b       1004
```

All id's and groups are sequential. What I would like is to select `id` and `device` based on groups and devices. Think of it as a pagination type selection. Getting the last `group` is a simple inner selection, but how do I select the second last group, or the third last group - etc.

I tried the row number function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY device ORDER BY group DESC) rn FROM data) tmp 
   WHERE rn = 1;
```

.. but changing `rn` is giving me the previous id, not the previous group.

I would like to end up with a selection that could accomodate these results:

device = a, group = latest:

```
id device  group  
10 a       1003
11 a       1003
```

device = a, group = latest - 1:

```
id device  group  
1  a       1000
2  a       1000
```

Any one know how to accomplish this?

Edit:

Use case is a GPS enabled device in a car, sending data every 30 seconds. Imagine going on a drive today. First you go to the shops, then you go home. the first trip is you driving to the shop. The second trip is you driving back. I want to show those trips on a map, but it means I need to identify your last trip, and then the trip before it - ad infinitum, until you run out of trips.

Comment: why do you have to show multiple rows per device?

Comment: If it speaks to the imagination more, the actual use case is a trip on a gps device located in a car, and I want to show the whole trip.

Comment: Sounds like an [X Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What are actually trying to do here?

Comment: @Bohemian I've added my use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
`with x as (
select distinct page
from test_table),
y as (
select x.page
,row_number() over (order by page desc) as row_num
from x)
select test_table.* from test_table join y on y.page = test_table.page
where y.row_num =2`
```

I will try to explain what I have did here. 
The first block(x) returns the distinct groups(pages in my case).

The second block(y) assigns row numbers to the groups in terms of their rank. In this case the ranking is in descending order of the pages.

Finally the third block, selects the desired value for the desired page. In case you want the pen-ultimate page , type rouw_num=2, if third from last use row_num =3 and likewise. 
You can play around with the values [here]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/190c06/26

Answer (score 1):

Use `dense_rank()`:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*, dense_rank() over (order by group_id desc) as seqnum
      from data d
      where device = 'a'
     ) d
where seqnum = 2;
```

Comment: This works as well, and it looks like it has less steps than the previous answer. Can I assume it's faster on large tables?

Comment: @jorg . . . This should have better performance.  You can test on your data and your system.